# Flash message not showing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash-message

i've some issue when trying to use flash message `flash[:notice]`. the flash message is not showing it's message

Here is my partial form view

```
<%= form_tag bulk_push_api_v1_notifications_path do |f| %>
<fieldset class="inputs">
    <legend>
        <span>Details</span>
    </legend>
        <% if flash[:notice].present? %>
          <p class='flash-notice'><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
        <% elsif flash[:error].present? %>
          <p class='flash-error'><%= flash[:error] %></p>
        <% end %>
    <ol>
        <li class="file input required" id="play_media_input">
             <%= label_tag(:message, "Message : ") %>
             <%= text_area_tag :message,  nil, :required => true %>
            <p class="inline-hints">Only text can be sent</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="actions">
    <ol>
        <li class="action input_action " id="play_submit_action">
            <%= submit_tag("Send Notification") %>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

and it will triggered this method from controller

```
def bulk_push
  begin
    User.send_bulk_notifications(params[:message])
    redirect_to admin_notification_path, :flash => { :notice => "Insufficient rights!" }
  rescue
    redirect_to admin_notification_path, :flash => { :error => "Error" }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code to display `flash` messages:

## controller

```
def bulk_push
  begin
    User.send_bulk_notifications(params[:message])
    redirect_to admin_notification_path, notice: "Insufficient rights!"
  rescue
    redirect_to admin_notification_path, alert: "Error"
  end

end
```

## app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<% if notice %>
  <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>
<% if alert %>
  <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
<% end %>

<style type="text/css">
  .alert-success{
    color: green;
  }
  .alert-danger{
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , it's really help me

Comment: @MuhammadRahmatullah vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: sure sir, but currently i got some errors when upvote your answer `Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 16 hours.`

Comment: @MuhammadRahmatullah Ok Np

Answer (score -1):

The flash provides a way to pass temporary primitive-types (String, Array, Hash) between actions. But you're trying to send flash notice as url_redirection parameters.
Just declare

```
flash[:notice] = "some msg"
```

before your redirection.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

Comment: it still doesn't work sir , i've change the code as your advice

Comment: `flash: {...` is a perfectly valid optional argument for the `redirect_to` method (though it's not an option for certain other redirection methods). https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to